# Erro no Laravel 4.2 - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

Tags: mysql, sql, iis, laravel-4, php-5

Estou com problemas em uma aplicação web utilizando Laravel 4.2 a mesma funcionava em um ambiente Windows 7 com IIS + PHP 5.6 porém tive que trocar de máquina e assim criar um novo ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Então montei um novo ambiente com a seguinte configuração: Windows 10 Home, com o IIS 10, PHP 5.6.40 e MySQL Community Server 8.0.19, a aplicação funciona bem até tentar efetuar Login/Criar Usuários, quando ocorre comunicação com o banco de dados, nesse momento retorna um erro com a seguinte mensagem:

**SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em buscas na internet encontrei alguns lugares dizendo que isso se trata de um bug no método de autenticação do MySQL, tentei criar um novo usuário para acessar a base com um método de acesso diferente, porém continua retornando o mesmo erro.

Alguém já passou por esse problema e tem alguma sugestão para solução?

Configuração de acesso a base de dados **database.php**:

```
<?php

return [

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*Default Connections*/
    'default' => 'mysql',

    /*Config Connections*/
    'connections' => [

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'proj',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '123456',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => '192.168.10.19',
            'database' => 'CEPs',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '1597xxx',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

    ],

    /*Config Migrations Path*/
    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Log do erro **laravel.log**:

```
[2020-06-25 18:32:05] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'PDO::__construct(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers' in C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:47
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(2, 'PDO::__construc...', 'C:\\PROJETOS\\pro...', 47, Array)
#1 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php(47): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'projetoX', 'veridian12345678', Array)
#2 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector.php(20): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=loca...', Array, Array)
#3 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php(57): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
#4 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php(46): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->createSingleConnection(Array)
#5 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php(176): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->make(Array, 'mysql')
#6 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php(64): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->makeConnection('mysql')
#7 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(2922): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->connection('mysql')
#8 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(2888): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection('mysql')
#9 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1849): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getConnection()
#10 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1790): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newBaseQueryBuilder()
#11 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1764): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQueryWithoutScopes()
#12 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider.php(87): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQuery()
#13 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Guard.php(354): Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider->retrieveByCredentials(Array)
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Auth\Guard->attempt(Array, false)
#15 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Manager.php(138): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(211): Illuminate\Support\Manager->__call('attempt', Array)
#17 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(211): Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager->attempt(Array, false)
#18 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\app\controllers\LoginController.php(35): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('attempt', Array)
#19 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\app\controllers\LoginController.php(35): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::attempt(Array, false)
#20 [internal function]: LoginController->efetuarLogin()
#21 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(231): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#22 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(93): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('efetuarLogin', Array)
#23 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(62): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(LoginController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'efetuarLogin')
#24 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(967): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'LoginController', 'efetuarLogin')
#25 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#26 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(109): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#27 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1033): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1001): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(781): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(745): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#32 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#33 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#34 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#35 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(641): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\public\index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#37 {main}

Next exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers' in C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:47
Stack trace:
#0 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php(0): PDO->__construct()
#1 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector.php(20): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=loca...', Array, Array)
#2 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php(57): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
#3 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php(46): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->createSingleConnection(Array)
#4 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php(176): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->make(Array, 'mysql')
#5 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php(64): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->makeConnection('mysql')
#6 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(2922): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->connection('mysql')
#7 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(2888): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection('mysql')
#8 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1849): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getConnection()
#9 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1790): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newBaseQueryBuilder()
#10 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1764): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQueryWithoutScopes()
#11 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider.php(87): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQuery()
#12 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Guard.php(354): Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider->retrieveByCredentials(Array)
#13 [internal function]: Illuminate\Auth\Guard->attempt(Array, false)
#14 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Manager.php(138): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(211): Illuminate\Support\Manager->__call('attempt', Array)
#16 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(211): Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager->attempt(Array, false)
#17 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\app\controllers\LoginController.php(35): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('attempt', Array)
#18 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\app\controllers\LoginController.php(35): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::attempt(Array, false)
#19 [internal function]: LoginController->efetuarLogin()
#20 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(231): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#21 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(93): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('efetuarLogin', Array)
#22 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(62): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(LoginController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'efetuarLogin')
#23 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(967): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'LoginController', 'efetuarLogin')
#24 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#25 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(109): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#26 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1033): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1001): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(781): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(745): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#31 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#32 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#33 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#34 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(641): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 C:\PROJETOS\projetoX\public\index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#36 {main} [] []
```

Comment: mostre seu mecanismo de conexão como banco de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nova versão MySQL alterou um conjunto de caracteres padrão para utf8mb4. Alguns clientes não reconhecem esse conjunto de caracteres. Portanto, quando o servidor relata seu conjunto de caracteres padrão para o cliente e o mesmo não sabe o que significa o servidor gera o erro que ocorreu com você.

Altere o conjunto de caracteres para utf8, para ser compatível com clientes não atualizados. Talvez o link que segue te ajude...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf

Comment: Realmente o problema é devido a alteração no conjunto de caracteres padrão no MySQL 8, localizei o arquivo de configuração **my.ini** em **"C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0"** e setei as configurações da seguinte forma: **default-character-set=utf8** e **character-set-server=utf8** o que solucionou meu problema. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: De nada Lenadro, sucesso!